# First meaningful paint event in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I was running audit with Chrome's lighthouse and I see in the report message saying:

```
Audit error: No usable firstMeaningfulPaint(candidate) events found in trace
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/prc8dw9lxjb83z0/Screenshot%202017-11-30%2017.06.28.png?dl=0

I'm trying to find how to actually mark the candidate for first meaningful pain but without any luck yet. Does anyone know how can this be resolved?

Comment: I think this is just flaky behavior on Lighthouse's end. There's nothing you need to do in your code to generate FMP candidates. Chrome generates them based on various load metrics. If you can consistently reproduce this issue on a certain page, you can file a bug at https://github.com/googlechrome/lighthouse/issues/new.